# Promote Windows Server 2012 to domain controller in an existing samba network

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba, solaris

I have a Windows Server that I want to use as a domain controller to push gpo's to workstations that are on a samba 3 domain served from an Oracle Solaris server. If I were to promote this server to a domain controller, can anyone here give me some advice on what I should expect? The samba domain is not an active directory domain it is a simple ldap server used for sharing printers and files and has never had a windows server as a memeber or dc.

I've never worked in a samba environment until recently and I need a way to centrally manage several hundred PC's. Any help, links, or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, Samba 3 ~= Windows 2000 Domain Functional Level. You'll need Samba 4 to support 2012 DC's

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: It's NT4 style domains. W2K introduced Active Directory.